# How to improve/increase full rank of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank

I have a matrix $W$ which can be decomposed as
$$ W=\left[
    \begin{array}{c|c}
      U & 0\\
      \hline
      Y&Z    \end{array}
\right] $$

In which, $U,Z$ are given and have $rank(U)=r_1,rank(Z)=r_2$. How can I design the matrix $Y$, so that $rank(W)$ is maximum? Thank all in advance

This is what I tried
Let see the general case first

$$ W=\left[
    \begin{array}{c|c}
      U & X\\
      \hline
      Y&Z    \end{array}
\right] $$

Assuming that all inverses exist, then

$$W^{-1}=\left[
    \begin{array}{}
      [U-XZ^{-1}Y]^{-1}& U^{-1}X[YU^{-1}X-Z]^{-1}\\
      [YU^{-1}-Z]^{-1}YU^{-1} & [Z-YU^{-1}X]^{-1}    
    \end{array}
\right] $$

Set $X=0$(zero matrix) then $W^{-1}$ becomes
$$W^{-1}=\left[
    \begin{array}{}
      U^{-1}& 0\\
      Z^{-1}YU^{-1} & Z^{-1}    
    \end{array}
\right] $$

From here, I have no idea to design matrix $W$

Comment: Do you know what the sizes of the blocks are?

Comment: Yes, the total size of $W_{n \times m}$ with $n=n_1+n_2$, $m=m_1+m_2$ ($U_{n_1 \times m_1},Z_{n_2 \times m_2}$)